# Flutter url_launcher NOT working for IOS (test on real device)

Tags: ios, flutter

here is my code which works fine on Android and opens URl on a browser:

```
  _launchURL(url) async {
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }
```

but for IOS I get this error:

```
2020-10-22 10:23:23.896883+0300 Runner[805:312838] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "(null)" - error: "Invalid input URL"
2020-10-22 10:23:23.899096+0300 Runner[805:313046] [VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: Could not launch https://manager.alkadhum-col.edu.iq/storage/test.pdf
```

I do not understand why is says `failed for URL: "(null)"` whereas the URL as printed is clearly not null, the program is not passing `canLaunch()` function.

I also tried `launch(url)` directly without `canLaunch(url)`  and I got this error :

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'The specified URL has an unsupported scheme. Only HTTP and HTTPS URLs are supported.'
```

Comment: How did you solve this?